# My.Application.MainWindow is Nothing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012, .net-3.5

After moving **`MainWindow.xaml`** in VB project using the Visual Studio into project folder **`Windows\MainWindow.xaml`** I've got some trouble (broken references etc.). I needed to re-create **`MainWindow.xaml`** to get them resolved (it was longer time ago, I don't remember exactly).

Currently, variable `My.Application.MainWindow` contains `Nothing` during runtime.

I've compared the project against blank project where `My.Application.MainWindow` contains correct reference during the runtime and found no place in original project where setting of `My.Application.MainWindow` is omitted (or something similar).

Do you have any experience on which place `My.Application.MainWindow` is being initialized in VisualStudio 2012 project?

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    'next line throws NullReferenceException
    Debug.Print("My.Application.MainWindow.Name = " & My.Application.MainWindow.Name)
    'some other code here...
End Sub
```

Comment: Project + Properties, Application tab, Startup URI setting.

Comment: @HansPassant - I wish it worked Hans. I checked it 5 times, I can see correct reference in there. I even tried to change it to another window and back. Something is badly broken :)

Comment: Look at the .vbproj file with a text editor, compare it to a new project.

Comment: @HansPassant - I've moved everything to new project just to find out the problem was elsewhere: `My.Application.MainWindow` value has limited lifetime. See the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that `My.Application.MainWindow` points to main window object **only if main window is open. It is `Nothing` otherwise.** So I had two issues:

1. In one of paths of my original code, I was accidentally closing main window, so `My.Application.MainWindow` became `Nothing` after calling `Close()`
2. In code shown in the question, it was **too early** to check for `My.Application.MainWindow` value – it was `Nothing` because the main window was not opened yet